# -Headers : The term '-Headers' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, - Azure functions running in cmd prompt with Invoke web request

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I have an **Azure Functions (Stack: .Net - HttpTrigger Template)** in ***VS Code*** with the below code:

```
public static class OnPaymentReceived
    {
        [FunctionName("OnPaymentReceived")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Received a payment.");

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
           
            return new OkObjectResult($"Thank you for your purchase");
        }
    }
```

I know that we can run the Azure Function in many ways, where I'm using `IWR` through Windows PowerShell using the below cmdlets:

```
iwr -Method POST `
-Uri http://localhost:7071/api/OnPaymentReceived
-Headers @{"Content-Type"="application/json"}`
-Body '{}'
```

I'm getting the successful output but an error related to the 3rd line of cmdlet which is:

**Output:**

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : Thank you for your purchase
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
                    Date: Fri, 24 Dec 2021 01:10:33 GMT
                    Server: Kestrel

                    Thank you for your purchase
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Transfer-Encoding, chunked], [Content-Type, text/plain; charset=utf-8], [Date, Fri, 24 Dec 2021
                    01:10:33 GMT], [Server, Kestrel]}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 27
```

**Exception:**
When I used the syntax of 3rd cmdlet like: `-Headers @{"Content-Type"="application/json"}`

```
-Headers : The term '-Headers' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:1
+ -Headers @{"Content-Type"="application/json"}`
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Headers:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I used the another syntax of 3rd cmdlet like:  `header('Content-type: application/json');`

```
header : The term 'header' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:1
+ header('Content-type: application/json');
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (header:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

-Body : The term '-Body' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:1
+ -Body '{}'
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Body:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to resolve this exception (What is the right syntax of this -Headers cmdlet) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -Headers : The term '-Headers' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

The error is caused because of the syntax error in the cmdlet.

```
iwr -Method POST `
-Uri http://localhost:7071/api/OnPaymentReceived `
-headers @{"Content-Type"="application/json"} `
-Body '{} '
```

After every line of command there must be  one space and apostrophe symbol  like the below format
(-cmdlet cmdends  `  ).

I have tried with the above cmdlets , you can see the output without any error.

[image]